# How to use the l3keys' .cs_set:Np key property?

Tags: expl3, l3keys

The `l3keys` documentation says:

> `.cs_set:Np ⟨key⟩ .cs_set:Np = ⟨control sequence⟩ ⟨arg. spec.⟩`
>
> Defines `⟨key⟩` to set `⟨control sequence⟩` to have `⟨arg. spec.⟩` and replacement text
> `⟨value⟩`.

But I don't understand how this `.cs_set:Np` key property can be used. Indeed, in the following MCE:

- `key-one .code:n    = \__mymodule_ditto:n #1` gives the expect result,
- `key-two .cs_set:Np = \__mymodule_ditto:n #1` gives an empty result.

Could you explain how to use the `.cs_set:Np` key property?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { mymodule }
{
  key-one .code:n    = \__mymodule_ditto:n #1 ,
  key-two .cs_set:Np = \__mymodule_ditto:n #1
}
\cs_set:Npn \__mymodule_ditto:n #1
  {
    #1
  }
\begin{enumerate}
\item \keys_set:nn { mymodule } { key-one = { Once~ upon~ a~ time,~ ... } }
\item \keys_set:nn { mymodule } { key-two = { Once~ upon~ a~ time,~ ... } }
\end{enumerate}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key defines/redefines a command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { mymodule } { 
  key-two .cs_set:Np = \__mymodule_ditto:nn #1 #2
 } 

\keys_set:nn { mymodule } { key-two = { Once~ upon~ a~ time,~ #1,~#2 
    ... } } 

\__mymodule_ditto:nn{hallo}{world}\par

\keys_set:nn { mymodule } { key-two = { #1!!!} }

\__mymodule_ditto:nn{hallo}{world}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

[image]